# How can I cache nested objects with Apollo Client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, contentful

I'm using the Contentful GraphQL API to fetch a collection of items, in this example football clubs.

```
query Clubs($limit: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
    clubCollection(limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
        total
        items {
            name
            description
        }
    }
}
```

The structure of the response is:

```json
clubCollection: {
  items: [{
    ... array of all the clubs
  }]
}
```

It looks like the Apollo `InMemoryCache` is only caching the full query in its ROOT_QUERY object. But not each individual club. The setup for the cache looks like this:

```json
new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        clubCollection: concatContentfulPagination()
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Does anyone know how I can target the clubs in `items` so that I can cache each individual club?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the answer from @xadm I realised I did not need to extend the `InMemoryCache` like so:

```json
new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        clubCollection: {
          items: { 
          
          },
          ...concatContentfulPagination()
        }
      },
    },
  },
})
```

But instead add it to the root of the typePolicies based on the type of the object, for me it is `Club`. When I added that it did work!

```json
new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Club: {
      keyFields: ['name']
    },
    Query: {
      fields: {
        clubCollection: concatContentfulPagination()
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items should have an `id` prop requested ... to be normalized - Apollo is normalizing cache GraphQL client

It's required to cache entries/types/subtypes properly.

https://graphql.org/learn/caching/

It, unique key can be `id`, `_id` or customized key per type using `typePolicies` - [customizing-identifier-generation-by-type](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-identifier-generation-by-type).

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#default-identifier-generation

In this case (no queryable `id` prop inside items), you should check in API (docs/specs/schema or explore network response body  - `__typename` prop of `items` object) the type of club items entries (probably `Club`) and customize cache policies like:

```
new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Club: {
      keyFields: ['name']
    },
```

... assuming `name` is unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware the object needs an ID, unfortunately the id of a Contentful object is in a ever deeper nested object: 

```graphql
 clubCollection(limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
        total
        items {
            sys: {
              id
            }
            name
            description
        }
    }
```

So maybe my question was wrong... The question would be, how can I access the array of clubs in items with typePolicies to set the field `name` for example as the `keyFields`?

Comment: You should see individual item entries in the cache ... you can use cache API (`readFragment`) to read them ... what do you mean by *'how can I access the array of clubs'* ? `items` array is a prop of response type (query returns some typed item? unknown? check `__typename` in network response details? check api/specs, (no `id`, not normalized)

Comment: Thanks again! I editted the original post with what I think is the solution. Is that indeed what you tried to tell me? :-)

Answer (score 0):

For this pupose you can use reactive variables. That way you can access clubs array anywhere in your code without rerunning query and perform any array operation on it.
Visit [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/) page for more info on it.